# UWP App Randomly Crashes When Returning to Previous Page

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-10-mobile

I have an app where I list some items and then change to another page for editing. In the edit page, I have some fields where i need to choose a value from a list which I load in another page. I call the list page from the edit page, passing a method from the edit page view model to be invoked when a selection is made so that I can update my model and bindings.

The problem is that sometimes, when returning to the edit page, the debugger breaks in the generated file App.g.i.cs with an

```
 "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." exception.
```

It fully displays the page with the correct bindings and selected values before breaking.

I've excluded possible errors from the async loading of the value list by replacing it with a dummy page and by removing any callbacks set by the edit page. The error still happened. 
The edit page has its navigation cache mode set to Required so I don't lose the previous changes. I tried without a required cache mode and still got the error.

<s>The only thing that seemed to resolve the issue was when I removed the bindings that used custom converters from the edit page xaml but I have those in other pages and never had a problem.</s> (See Update)

The debugger break in the generated code:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
```

This is the xaml for the edit page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
    <converters:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormat" />
    <converters:DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter x:Key="DateOffset" />
    <converters:DateTimeToTimeSpanConverter x:Key="TimeSpan" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <fieldSelectControl:BackButtonAndTitle Title="Page Title" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="HomeButton"
                Width="70"
                Height="50"
                Background="Black"
                Content="&#xE80F;"
                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                FontSize="30" />
        <TextBlock Name="PageTitle"
                   FontSize="36"
                   Text="{Binding OrderTitle}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ProgressRing Grid.Row="2" IsActive="{Binding IsLoading}" />

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2"
                  Height="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Visibility="{Binding Path=FinishedLoading,
                                       Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">

        <StackPanel Margin="20,10,20,30">
            <TextBlock Margin="0,5,0,5"
                       Style="{StaticResource DetailLabel}"
                       Text="Date" />
            <DatePicker Date="{Binding Day, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DateOffset}}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0,15,0,5"
                       Style="{StaticResource DetailLabel}"
                       Text="Type" />
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedHourType, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <TextBlock Margin="0,15,0,5"
                       Style="{StaticResource DetailLabel}"
                       Text="Start" />
            <TimePicker ClockIdentifier="24HourClock" Time="{Binding StartTime, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpan}}" />

            <TextBlock Margin="0,5,0,5"
                       Style="{StaticResource DetailLabel}"
                       Text="End" />
            <TimePicker ClockIdentifier="24HourClock" Time="{Binding EndTime, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpan}}" />

            <TextBlock Margin="0,15,0,5"
                       Style="{StaticResource DetailLabel}"
                       Text="Amount" />
            <TextBox InputScope="Number" Text="{Binding HValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />



            <fieldSelectControl:FieldWithIconSelector x:Name="fsSelect"
                                                      IconClickedEvent="btnClose_Click"
                                                      IconField="&#xE109;"
                                                      TitleField="Add..."
                                                      TitleIconField=""
                                                      ValueField="" />

            <ScrollViewer Height="Auto"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ListView x:Name="lstOrders"
                          Height="auto"
                          MaxHeight="600"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                          ItemClick="lstOrders_ItemClick"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEmployees,
                                                Mode=OneWay}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Responsible">
                            <fieldSelectControl:FieldWithIconSelector x:Name="fsEmployees"
                                                                      IconClickedEvent="fsEmployees_IconClickedEvent"
                                                                      IconField=""
                                                                      TitleField=""
                                                                      TitleIconField=""
                                                                      ValueField="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListView>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <Button Name="btnSave"
                    Margin="0,20,0,15"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Click="btnSave_Click"
                    Visibility="{Binding Path=FinishedSaving,
                                         Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Background="#0099cc"
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    Padding="5">
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                       FontSize="25"
                                       Text="&#xE74E;" />
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Save" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>



    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Code for the DateOffset Converter:

```
public class DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
                return new DateTimeOffset(date);
            }
            else
                return new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        DateTimeOffset dto = (DateTimeOffset)value;
        return dto.DateTime;
    }
}
```

Code for the TimeOffset Converter:

```
public class DateTimeToTimeSpanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
                return new TimeSpan(date.Ticks);
            }
            else
                return new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = (TimeSpan)value;
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(ts.Ticks);

        return dt;
    }
}
```

Given the code where the debugger breaks, the error seems to be on the xaml side and, as I said, removing the date and time pickers, which are the only elements where the binding uses a custom converter, seems to fix it.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Further testing has brought to my attention that removing the custom converters doesnt actually fix the issue, it just increases the number of navigations until the error happens. I've tried removing the bindings altogether and still got the error. Removing every element but the button that calls the next page seems to work but at this point I can't tell for sure if it actually fixes the issue or just mitigates it.

On a side note, navigating back to the first page using the phone `Back` button works flawlessly. The error only seems to happen if `Frame.GoBack()` is explicitly invoked.

Comment: The inner exception?

Comment: Oh sorry, the message is "Unspecified error" but the actual exception is "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." with ErrorCode = -2147467259. The actuall Inner Exception is null.

Comment: After you removeing `<TimePicker ClockIdentifier="24HourClock" Time="{Binding StartTime, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpan}}" />`, it works well? Could you please give the code of `TimeSpan` converter?

Comment: From this page navigate to other page and return back will lead this issue?

Comment: @Sunteen Yes, but not 100% of the time, sometimes it works just fine and, as I said, the page loads and binds correctly before the break occurs.

Comment: @Will Added exception details

Comment: I'd wrap all your `Frame.GoBack()/Navigate()` calls in a single method that checks for reentrancy (asserts that a custom global `isNavigating` field is `false`, then sets it to `true` before calling `Frame.GoBack/Navigate`, then sets it back to `false`).

Comment: @FilipSkakun Didn't work. I'm currently testing a new approach where I let the user select an item from the list but have him go back manually instead of calling 'Frame.GoBack()'. It's not a solution but if this doesn't generate that exception, it's better than nothing and should provide some insight about the nature of this error.

Comment: Also make sure to check `CanGoBack` before trying to navigate.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue and have isolated it to the TimePicker control; i.e. just removing this control from the view resolves the issue. Did you make any progress on a solution?

Answer (score 0):

These sorts of exceptions don't provide too many hints as to what's causing them, but there are a few things you could try:

- I'd remove the `ScrollViewer` from around `lstOrders`. It doesn't add any value, yet it could break virtualization of the `ListView` causing it to try to use arbitrary amounts of memory and CPU if you'd accidentally removed `MaxHeight` set on the `lstOrders`.
- The `btnSave` template is bad as it removes interactive feedback elements.
- Make sure the properties you bind to are not changed off the UI/Dispatcher thread.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the 'ScrollViewer'.
Removed the 'ScrollViewer', 'btnSave' Template and double checked the bound properties. None of this worked. The properties are being changed in the UI thread but even if they aren't changed at all the exception still occurs.

Comment: Then the best way I think would be to try elimination - remove chunks of code until it stops crashing. You could also add some trace calls in your converter to see if it gets called right before the crash.

Comment: The converter isn't called even when the crash doesnt happen because no change is made to the property anyway.
Edited question with new info and corrections.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments on the question, I have been experiencing this issue today. It was relatively straight forward to isolate the issue to the TimePicker control and, more specifically, the two way binding on the Time property of the control.

However, it was less straight forward to work out why it was happening. It seems to be some issue around visibility (I experience the issue when moving my app to the background) and updating the bound value. Regardless, I tried a variety of things to no avail.

In the end, I tried changing the binding expression from the traditional `{Binding}` syntax to the compiled `{x:Bind}` and, fortunately, the problem went away.

Perhaps, give that a shot and see if it solves your problem. Obviously the TimePicker will need to be inside a `DataTemplate` with a data type specific or - as in my case - a user control with custom dependency properties.